# Highcharts formatting: labels, datapoints and scale?

Tags: highcharts

I have a couple of formatting questions, as you'll see I'm running a very small chart 225*150...

1. How do I remove the x-axis labels? I still want the information in the tooltip, just not along the axis. I've tried...

   ```
   xAxis: {
       title:{
           categories: ['2008-2009', '2009-2010', '2010-2011', '2011-2012'],
           enabled:false
       }
   },
   ```

...but it still shows "0, .5, 1, 1.5 etc..."

1. I've adjusted the thickness of my lines but now the datapoint indicators themselves can't bee seen. Can somebody show me which value controls that?
2. Last one, how do I set zero for the y-axis scale?

Here's [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/johnlayne/z6ZLt/6/)!

Thanks!

UPDATE: Added suggestions to original fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disable the [xAxis.labels](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.labels) you set `enabled` to false:

```
xAxis: {
    categories: ['2008-2009', '2009-2010', '2010-2011', '2011-2012'],
    enabled: false,
    labels: {
        enabled: false
    }
}
```

For doing "set zero for the y-axis scale" you set the [`yAxis.min`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.min) value to 0:

```
yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    title: {
        text: ''
    },
    plotLines: [{
        value: 0,
        width: 1,
        color: '#808080'
    }]
}
```

To handle the size of the [line](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.line) + [markers](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.line.marker) you need to modify their properties in :

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        marker: {
            radius: 1.5
        },
        pointWidth: 1
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. If you look at the fiddle, the y-axis goes from 13k to 17k. I'd like the baseline to be 0 so it would go from 0 to 17k and flatten out the line.

Comment: Great! I've updated the original fiddle. Any ideas about the larger data points? thanks again!

Comment: Updated the answer. I highly recommend checking out their API docs.

Comment: I was just bouncing around in there. Holy cow this thing is customizable! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In this block:

```
xAxis: {
    title:{
        categories: ['2008-2009', '2009-2010', '2010-2011', '2011-2012'],
        enabled:false
    }
},
```

You have

1) the categories property listed inside the title attribute, and 
2) you have `enabled: false` set for the title attribute

`categories` is a property of the axis directly, and the `enabled: false`  should be applied to the labels, not the title.

"I've adjusted the thickness of my lines but now the datapoint indicators themselves can't bee seen. Can somebody show me which value controls that?"

Primarily the marker radius property:

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.marker.radius

You can also look at the lineWidth property of the marker.

"Last one, how do I set zero for the y-axis scale?"

axis min property:

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.min

updated fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/z6ZLt/8/